# How do I use a binary buffer tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox, dropbox-sdk-js

I have a program that simply signs into my dropbox account and uses .filesdownload which returns a file binary that looks like this:

`content_hash: '1f52337b503d8baed7c11cabecd526d33ba80adadeae2767aff133624cbf53aa', fileBinary: <Buffer 7b 22 3c 40 32 34 39 36 30 38 36 33 32 39 33 35 36 34 35 31 38 36 3e 22 3a 20 5b 7b 22 72 69 63 68 61 72 64 63 68 31 65 65 73 65 22 3a 20 22 5f 7c 57 ... 223685 more bytes> }`

My goal is to get it downloaded as the text file it should be, or if the program could read it without downloading that would be cool too.

I just need someone to explain what is going on and how can I convert this binary buffer tag into some kind of readable / downloaded form?

Comment: What code is being used to get this data? The term `.filesdownload` is not useful without context. The `fileBinary` data is an `ArrayBuffer`, this is a newer data type in JS which is a part of [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Typed_arrays). Create an `ArrayBuffer` with the data, and a typed array view for data that's all a single type or a data view if it's varying types. Then figure what the character encoding is - UTF-8 is common for text, but JS uses UTF-16 to represent Strings internally (noteworthy if you're trying to save data as text).